# ruby - custom validation is not called

Tags: ruby, validation, activemodel

I have two classes; customer and reservation. And my project is consist of only ruby code, not rails project.

Class reservation reads bulk json file line by line which includes customer hash.

From that hash, I create customer object.

Here's the code within the reservation class.

```
    def parse_json
        File.open(@filename, "r" ).each do |line|    
            @customers << Customer.new(JSON.parse(line))
        end

        return @customers
    end
```

And in customer.rb I have the following;

```
    validates_presence_of :hash
    validate :hash_should_include_all_fields
    attr_reader :name, :userid, :latitude, :longitude, :distance  

    def hash_should_include_all_fields
        puts "I'm here #{hash}"
        if hash.assert_valid_keys('user_id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude')
            puts "Valid"
        else
            puts "Not valid"
        end
    end
```

However as I create customer objects, `hash_should_include_all_fields` method is not called.

What do I miss in here, that would be great if you can help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving the model? Or checking validity? Models aren't validated just when you instantiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `new` which will build a `Customer` object but do nothing more.

Calling `create!` or `create` will also run validations and write the Object to the database if it's an active_record model.

If you don't want to write it to the databas you can call `valid?` on the instance created with `new`

Comment: also `save` run validation.

Comment: Hi Axel, thank you for your answer, but regarding calling "new" for creating instance, validates_presence_of also does not work. So when I give nil parameters to customer class, it also gave "no method error for nil class". So what's the best way to create those objects?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by 'parameters to customer class'? 'The best way' really depends on more than one can tell by the few lines shown. Here is a slightly more detailed answer on new vs. create http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333163/question-about-create-and-new-methods-in-activerecord-class

Comment: what I'm saying is, calling Customer.new(<parameters>). If some those parameters are nil, then I'll get error on initialize method.

Comment: That's a different problem. Post a new question with more context of the stack trace where exactly this error occurs