# Simple Form on Submit is not sending the input to MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So as you all can see in the screen shot below in my blog form when I click submit when creating a new blog the parameters get sent but never actually get inserted into the MySQL command. Which you can see the post in the background is empty except for the Timestamp.

Now with that being said this same form is used for my Edit Blog page. My form is a partial rendered in the new blog page and the edit blog page. So if I go edit that same blog page that was created with no input up submit of the edit's the parameters actually go through and then the blog post will show will all the information from your edits.

[image: Screen Shot of Web-console not importing the parameters to MySQL]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]

# Index action to render all posts
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

# New action for creating post
def new
 @post = Post.new
end

# Create action saves the post into database
def create
  @post = Post.new
if @post.save(post_params)
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post!"
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
else
  flash[:alert] = "Error creating new post!"
  render :new
end
end

# Edit action retrives the post and renders the edit page
def edit
end

# Update action updates the post with the new information
def update
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post!"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
    render :edit
  end
end

# The show action renders the individual post after retrieving the id
def show
end

# The destroy action removes the post permanently from the database
def destroy
  if @post.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted post!"
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:strain, :straintype, :style, :light, :temp, :breeder, :private, :notes, :nutrients)
end

def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

I just don't understand why the edit saves correctly but no the initial submit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think maybe it should be .create(post_params) instead of .new

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create

[Rails: Difference between create and new methods in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333163/rails-difference-between-create-and-new-methods-in-activerecord)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried just create without the post_params. Still trying to understand these nuances